# How to detect keyboard input with TVML/TVJS

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml, tvjs

As the title suggests, I would like to know how to detect keyboard input using a TVML template and using the TVJS design pattern found in the [Apple Catalog Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/samplecode/TVMLCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html)

For example: when Search.xml.js is displayed, and the user selects the 'a' key on the keyboard, how can I detect that they have selected the 'a' key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into the Apple Docs I was able to find the answer.

Here is the reference for [Keyboard onTextChange](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSKeyboard_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instp/Keyboard/onTextChange)

Here is an example of it's use:

```
var doc = Presenter.makeDocument(resource);
var searchField = doc.getElementById("SearchField"); //I added an id to the searchField to make it easy to access.
var keyboard = searchField.getFeature("Keyboard");
    keyboard.onTextChange = function () {                                
      swiftLog(keyboard.text);
    };
```